# Add custom text color WordPress 3.9 TinyMCE 4 Visual editor

Tags: plugins, multisite, visual-editor

I had a code snippet which would help me to add some custom color to the visual editor text color dropdown along with the default colors. I'm pasting the snippet below.

```
function change_mce_options( $init ) {
  $default_colours = '000000,993300,333300,003300,003366,000080,333399,333333,800000,FF6600,808000,008000,008080,0000FF,666699,808080,FF0000,FF9900,99CC00,339966,33CCCC,3366FF,800080,999999,FF00FF,FFCC00,FFFF00,00FF00,00FFFF,00CCFF,993366,C0C0C0,FF99CC,FFCC99,FFFF99,CCFFCC,CCFFFF,99CCFF,CC99FF,FFFFFF';
  $custom_colours = 'e14d43,d83131,ed1c24,f99b1c,50b848,00a859,00aae7,282828';
  $init['theme_advanced_text_colors'] = $default_colours . ',' . $custom_colours;
  $init['theme_advanced_more_colors'] = true;
  return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'change_mce_options');
```

After wordpress 3.9 update it stopped working, I've tried a lot to fix it, but I am unable to do it, can you please help me out?

Comment: Please take a look at the latest TinyMCE topics, you should find your answer there.

Comment: I did but did not find any alternative to `theme_advanced_text_colors` all they were saying is how to add new buttons. But mine is totally different. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Aleksandar Urošević addressed this specific scenario](http://urosevic.net/wordpress/tips/custom-colours-tinymce-4-wordpress-39/) (which is different than adding a button, as you've noted).

This is the WP 3.9 approach:

```
function mytheme_change_tinymce_colors( $init ) {
    $default_colours = '
        "000000", "Black",
        "993300", "Burnt orange",
        "333300", "Dark olive",
        "003300", "Dark green",
        "003366", "Dark azure",
        "000080", "Navy Blue",
        "333399", "Indigo",
        "333333", "Very dark gray",
        "800000", "Maroon",
        "FF6600", "Orange",
        "808000", "Olive",
        "008000", "Green",
        "008080", "Teal",
        "0000FF", "Blue",
        "666699", "Grayish blue",
        "808080", "Gray",
        "FF0000", "Red",
        "FF9900", "Amber",
        "99CC00", "Yellow green",
        "339966", "Sea green",
        "33CCCC", "Turquoise",
        "3366FF", "Royal blue",
        "800080", "Purple",
        "999999", "Medium gray",
        "FF00FF", "Magenta",
        "FFCC00", "Gold",
        "FFFF00", "Yellow",
        "00FF00", "Lime",
        "00FFFF", "Aqua",
        "00CCFF", "Sky blue",
        "993366", "Brown",
        "C0C0C0", "Silver",
        "FF99CC", "Pink",
        "FFCC99", "Peach",
        "FFFF99", "Light yellow",
        "CCFFCC", "Pale green",
        "CCFFFF", "Pale cyan",
        "99CCFF", "Light sky blue",
        "CC99FF", "Plum",
        "FFFFFF", "White"
        ';
    $custom_colours = '
        "e14d43", "Color 1 Name",
        "d83131", "Color 2 Name",
        "ed1c24", "Color 3 Name",
        "f99b1c", "Color 4 Name",
        "50b848", "Color 5 Name",
        "00a859", "Color 6 Name",
        "00aae7", "Color 7 Name",
        "282828", "Color 8 Name"
        ';
    $init['textcolor_map'] = '['.$default_colours.','.$custom_colours.']';
    $init['textcolor_rows'] = 6; // expand colour grid to 6 rows
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mytheme_change_tinymce_colors');
```

You don't need to include the default colors or change the grid size, of course, but I like this as a starting point.